# Do you gain XP for earning medals in Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Do you gain XP for earning medals in Pokémon Go?

I caught a few Pidgeys and then two things happened at the same time.

1. I was awarded a badge for catching Flying-type Pokémon, and
2. I was awarded XP.

I'm wondering: were the XP earned for catching the Pidgeys or for getting the badge?

Answer (score 9):

They were for catching the pidgey. As of now there are no rewards for any of the badges, even golden ones.

Source: Personal experience

Answer (score 2):

You do not get XP from earning medals in Pokemon GO. I have tried seeing they do give XP, but it does not. I've seen several of my friends and other players talk about how useless medals are since they award no XP.

Answer (score 1):

You do not earn experience for completing a medal.

You do gain 100 experience for catching a Pokemon, and 500 bonus experience for catching one that you haven't caught before.

Answer (score -3):

Actually you do get xp for attaining medals just not a lot from what I can tell. Here's proof as my partner says you don't but I have just sat here feeding berries to Pokemon in gyms nothing else and got my silver medal for berries and xp for it too.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Actually, yes you do gain XP for earning those medals. The XP shows up right above the avatar portrait when you earn a badge. It's usually not a large amount, but I believe I received 7000XP when I earned the full Scientist medal.

Comment: Pretty sure that was just the combined XP for evolving the Pokémon that got you the medal.